# Requests throw when using loadModel

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I tried to use a viewer API for using offline data(SVF) .
When I called loadModel, any requests sent as follows.

```
https://ase.autodesk.com/adp/v1/analytics/upload
https://raas-assets.autodesk.com/StaticContent/BaseAddress?family=protein
https://raas-assets.autodesk.com/StaticContent/BaseAddress?family=prism
```

What does this request mean?
Is it checking see if data is correct?

Answer (score 2):

The first one is for is internal to the viewer for properties access. The 2 others are internal for the viewer to access material definition for rendering purpose. Protein material are current/legacy material library (proprietary, and requires specific libraries from NVidia), Prism is the new future material library which is open (json information format)