# use viewer API in a completely private network

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to use viewer API in a completely private network, do you have any problems in this case?

[Requests throw when using loadModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441316/requests-throw-when-using-loadmodel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends what you mean by 'complete private network'

- if you want to use the viewer by storing the translation results (svf bubbles) on you network, and serving bubbles' files from one of your server, then it is ok (we call this offline viewing) - then you also need to copy the viewer javascript files on your server to do that. We got an example to do this at: https://extract.autodesk.io/ and source code at: https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io
- if you want to do something different from what I wrote above, you would need to contact us @ forge.help@autodesk.com and explain in more details what you want to do

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I thought "offline" = "disconected network” (I mean “complete private network”).

I tried disconected  network from my PC. 
Although it was requested to ase.autodesk.com, ase.autodesk.com, SVF data was displayed.
I'm worried that error is occurring but data is displayed.

I’ll contact to forge.help@autodesk.com.
Thanks,